# Query Sql Like String

Tags: sql, sql-like

I need help for sql query LIKE.
Value for column in database is same below:

```
 record 1 : "3,13,15,20"
 record 2 : "13,23,14,19"
 record 3 : "3,14,15,19,20"......
```

for now I want to get the most accurate record with a value of 3
This is my query :

```
SELECT * FROM accounts where type like '%3%'
```

This query will find all record with value exist is '3' eg: 13,23 .... 
And It does not solve my problem.

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Please specify database engine you're using in tags

Comment: Also, a table has _rows_, not _records_...

Comment: @jarlh I seem to see _record_ and _row_ used pretty interchangeably.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, same people who say _field_ instead of _column_? (The ANSI SQL specification uses row and column exclusively.)

Comment: @jarlh: you're absolutely right - relational databases have tables with **rows** and **columns** - but it seems like a struggle in vain to try and convince the IT crowd to be precise and use the proper, correct lingo :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE CONCAT(',', type, ',') LIKE '%,3,%';
```

[image]

### Demo

This trick places commas around the end of the `type` CSV string, so that we all we have to do is then check for `,3,` anywhere in that string.

By the way, it is generally not desirable to store CSV data like this in your SQL tables.  Instead, consider normalizing your data and storing those CSV values across separate rows.